# skimagedecoder::factory returned null, Skipping frames in Android

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-bitmap

I am using a GridView to display the images of albumart, for that i am creating a adapter, below is the code of my getView function of adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    FrameLayout albumLayout = (FrameLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.album, viewGroup, false);

    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)albumLayout.findViewById(R.id.iconItem);

    int albumId = keys[position];


    Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId);
    Bitmap image = null;
    try {
        image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, albumArtUri);
        //image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 80, 80, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.musicimage);
    }

    imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
    String albumName = albumMap.get(albumId);

    TextView albumNameView = (TextView)albumLayout.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
    albumNameView.setText(albumName);
    albumLayout.setTag(albumId);

    return albumLayout;

}
```

I have 4 fragments inside a ViewPager and when i swipe to the album page then it gets stuck there and i am getting skimagedecoder::factory returned null, Skipping frames in logs.

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this and how can i make it more efficient so that while swiping the view should not get stuck.

Comment: facing the same problem.